# UIView drag event

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an slide show application. There is a UIView on main screen, I want when someone slide his fingers horizontally it moves to next screen.

What this event is called? (slide fingers horizontally/vertically)
How can i detect this event? Want to call a method xyz on this event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). 
If not, then you can use [touchesMoved:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:) to detect the drag event. In this event handler you need to compare the coordinates to detect whether it is moving horizontally or vertically.